# ROS2 CANopen Stack

Tags: ros2, motor, ros-canopen

I'm trying to implement the ros2_canopen package for my Motor. So, i installed the package and set up all the configuration stuff. If i started the launch-file, I get following error message:

```
[device_container_node-1] [INFO] [1704728251.111151277] [device_container_node]: Added /master to executor
[device_container_node-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
[device_container_node-1]   what():  Device: No such file or directory
```

I'm note sure, which Device is meant. So, I only wanted to implement the CiA Profile 301, in the first step.

```
options:
 dcf_path: "@BUS_CONFIG_PATH@"
 
master:
 node_id: 1
 driver: "ros2_canopen::MasterDriver"
 package: "canopen_master_driver"
 baudrate: 500
 
nodes:
 node_id: 0x02
 dcf: "eds-file"
 package: "canopen_proxy_driver"
 driver: "ros2_canopen::ProxyDriver"
```

That's my yaml file for the configuration. Maybe someone has an idea, what could be the reason for this error message. Thanks a lot in advance.

Launchfile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
from ament_index_python import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

def generate_launch_description():
    """Generate launch description with multiple components."""
    path_file = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    ld = LaunchDescription()  # Beachten Sie hier den korrigierten Import 'LaunchDescription'.

    device_container = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            [
                os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("canopen_core"), "launch"),
                "/canopen.launch.py",
            ]
        ),
        launch_arguments={
            "master_config": os.path.join(
                get_package_share_directory("ros2_canopen_config"),
                "config",
                "motor",
                "master.dcf",
            ),
            "master_bin": os.path.join(
                get_package_share_directory("ros2_canopen_config"),
                "config",
                "motor",
                "master.bin",
            ),
            "bus_config": os.path.join(
                get_package_share_directory("ros2_canopen_config"),
                "config",
                "motor",
                "bus.yml",
            ),
            "can_interface_name": "can0",
        }.items(),

    )

    ld.add_action(device_container)

    return ld
```

Henne

Comment: Can you expand your question to contain links to the launch file that you are trying?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure, i added my launch file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the `ros2_canopen` framework, but taking a look at the samples, you have the `bus.yml` configuration file that must be expanded and installed via a cmake macro `generate_dcf`.

The `simple` exmaple does that here: https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros2_canopen/blob/7687f3276107d81f52e1f961566942508eb07d85/canopen_tests/CMakeLists.txt#L13C1-L13C21

Once you have verified that the `bus.yml` is being properly expanded (and it hasn't corrected the issue) it may be worthwhile to run the node under `gdb` to see where the exception is coming from.

```
gdb --args /opt/ros/rolling/lib/canopen_core/device_container_node --ros-args \
  --param can_interface_name:=vcan0 \
  --param master_bin:="" \
  --param master_config:="" \
  --param bus_config:=""
```

Once the node is running under gdb, you should be able to enter at the prompt to catch where the exception is happening and then print the backtrace.

```
# Instruct the debugger to stop at "throw statements"
(gdb) catch throw
# Start node
(gdb) run
# .... Once exception occurs
# Generate backtrace
(gdb) backtrace
```